# What does 100 MeV/u mean? How is it different from 100A MeV?

Tags: experimental-physics, subatomic

I have just started reading some research papers(nuclear) and I am getting really confused between the above two representations.
Please help me and kindly use layman language.

Answer (score 1):

The unit "u" is a standard atomic mass unit. The value of 1 u is set such that a carbon-12 atom has a mass of exactly 12 u. In other words, 1 u is exactly 1/12 of the mass of a carbon-12 atom. You may also see this unit being referred to as 1 Dalton, especially in chemistry.

The number $A$ is the number of protons and neutrons in the nucleus.

So, if you're given an energy in terms of MeV/u, then the total energy of the nucleus is the number you're given multiplied by the mass of the nucleus in u. If instead, you're given an energy in terms of $A$MeV, then the total energy of the nucleus is the number you're given multiplied by the number of nucleons in the nucleus.

In other words, the first quantity is energy per unit mass, and the second quantity is energy per nucleon.